# Unpacking Attributes from OSM

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, voronoi-thiessen

I am an Amateur user of QGIS and just started using OSM data as a part of a project where I need to create approximate postal code boundaries.

I used QGIS with OSM data to create Voronoi Polygons, then Dissolve them and last intersect them with the land map (so there are no polygons inside the sea).

When I load the OSM data (points) I get some attributes, but the one I really care is inside the `other_tags` with the name `addr:postcode`:

`"office"=>"energy_supplier","addr:city"=>"Î˜ÎµÏƒÏƒÎ±Î»Î¿Î½Î¯ÎºÎ·","addr:street"=>"ÎšÏ„Î¹ÏÎ¹Î±ÎºÏŒ Î£Ï…Î³ÎºÏÏŒÏ„Î·Î¼Î± Ganas & Ganas","addr:postcode"=>"57001","contact:email"=>"thes@volterra.gr","contact:phone"=>"+302310475308","opening_hours"=>"Mo-Fr 09:00-17:00","contact:website"=>"https://www.volterra.gr/grafeia-thessalonikis"`
[image]

Can I unpack somehow this attribute inside `other_tags` and move it along with the first level attributes?

The OSM I am using also can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_U-jBodNHFbd1bPkS67r2Wq0eLABhvQa/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Do you interested in a specific tag in other_tags or you want to unpack all of them?Other_tag is sometimes really long.

Comment: hey @Nil I am interested in postcode!